# Windows Phone 8.1: MessageDialog Text Style

Tags: text, windows-phone-8.1, messagedialog

I want to style the MessageDialog text and align its text to the right instead of left.

How can I style the MessageDialog text in Windows Phone **8.1**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ContentDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx) instead. You can build it using Visual Studio template (Project -> Add -> New Item -> Content Dialog)

Comment: Thanks. How can I show ContentDialog? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @JohnCroneh Have you opened the link I provided to you? The sample is at the bottom of the reference.